# CSS - Position an element in percent from its own width

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the center of an element (regardless of its height) over the bottom of its parent. I thought i'd go with absolute but nothing really makes sense. See picture below :

[image]

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

How can I have this result ?

EDIT : Thanks to @Gaby aka G. Petrioli I found my solution :

```css
#red{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position:relative;
}
#blue{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  right:3%;
  
  /* here is the magic solution*/
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
        <div id="blue"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So you need the blue div to be centered to the red one?

Comment: Yes pretty much !

Comment: "Run code snippet" is clearly not centered...

Comment: the center of the blue element sits on the edge of the red one, which was the desired result.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use absolute position to place it at the bottom, and then use transform translate to move it 50% upward since that work in regard to its own height.

So

```
.red{position:relative}
.blue{
   position:absolute;
   top:100%;
   right:50px;
   transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **CSS Positioning**, like:

```
.red {
  position: relative;
}

.blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; // Will be at exact bottom
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); // Will pull 50% (of blue) upwards & 50% from the right as well
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but I might have not formulated my question correctly. I wanted to position the center of my blue div on the bottom of the parent red div !

Comment: @MarineLeBorgne Oh! It's simple. You can check out my answer again!

Answer (score 2):

[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=a) `translate()` will calculate % from the size of the container itself.

> **Initial value**  none
>
> **Applies to** transformable elements
>
> **Inherited**  no
>
> **Percentages**    **`refer to the size of bounding box`**
>
> **Media**  visual
>
> **Computed value** as specified, but with relative lengths converted into absolute lengths
>
> **Animation type** a transform
>
> **Canonical order**    the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar
>
> **Creates stacking context**   yes

below a demo showing it in action once the box is aligned to bottom and centered.

```css
.red {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background:/* see center*/
  linear-gradient(to left,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%),
  linear-gradient(to top,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%) 
  crimson;
  }

.blue {
  width: 40%;
  min-height:3em;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(0, 119, 204);
                transform: translate(50%, 50%); /* what you look for */
}
body {
display:table;
border-spacing:1em;
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="blue">.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="red">
  <div class="blue"> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="red">
  <div class="blue"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[official](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/) and [to learn further](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#red{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  
}

#blue{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  top: calc(100% - 50px);
  /* 100% - it's width/2 */
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

If `#blue`'s `width` is `200px`, `top: calc(100% - 100px)`.

If `#blue`'s `width` is `500px`, `top: calc(100% - 250px)`.

Comment: Nice idea, but my content is generated dynamically so I can't use pixel values ! :) I found a solution though ! 
Thanks !

Comment: @MarineLeBorgne which solution? using `transform`?